# Download a file using WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, download, browser, webbrowser-control

i'm trying to automate the file download from a web page, the problem is, that web return directly the file. for example, http://www.someweb.com/generatefile.aspx, when i navigate to that page, a file is returning.
I tried with WebClient, but didn't work, always give error 500, however if i try through whit IExplorer or Firefox, work well. So, i trying with WebBrowser control, which i made all other things, such as login to web.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, "D:/ss.pdf");  //Here error 500
```

and with WebBrowser

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.FileDownload += new EventHandler(wb_FileDownload); //in the event handler i not found how save the file
wb.Navigate(url);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A late answer for future references: `URLDownloadToFile` or `URLDownloadToCacheFile` [can be used for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025793/1768303).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a bit more configuring, but I would recommend using the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) instead.

If you know the expected file type, then you can create a file on the filesystem with the known type and get a stream reference for it.  Then just write the response stream returned by [HttpWebRequest::GetResponse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx).

I've tried using the classes you mentioned in the past, but always fall back on using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.  As I said earlier, they are a bit more low level, but in a lot of scenarios, the additional control over the low level HTTP functions has been helpful in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an [FTPWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)?  The WebBrowser is made for GUI style interaction, not really for automation...

Comment: Yes, but it's a http web request... so ftp don't fit.